# Launch smart on FHIR app outside launchpad

Tags: javascript, html, hl7-fhir

Requirement: Open smart on FHIR app from out custom website when clicking on button without using any launchpad.

On button click event I tried to call launch url as like "https://localhost:44309/launch?launch=xyz123&iss=https://open-ic.epic.com/Argonaut/api/FHIR/Argonaut"" . But i'm getting error message saying **"error=invalid_grant&error_description=Invalid+launch+token&state=45373359"**. Is this correct way of launching smart on  FHIR app without using LaunchPad? or Is there any way? Please Advice

Comment: Sounds like a "standalone" launch to me - have you followed the instructions for one of those?

Comment: No. it's EHR Launch only.. usually we will send launch parameter in the launch url. I want to know how they are generating launch value?. example we can take Open Epic

Comment: Just got some info, Smart App Launcher generating launch token using selected patients and users. But in the Open epic saying "launch contains a SMART on FHIR launch token". I don't know how they are  getting this token and from where?

Comment: @kavithaK I'm not really following what you are after here.  Can you provide an end-to-end summary of what you are looking for in this integration?  Are you wanting to launch your app from within Epic (which our open.epic LaunchPad simulates)?  This might be a better suited for open@epic.com rather than StackOverflow if you want to send an e-mail summary there.

Comment: @Cooper Okay. Let me explain the situation. We have our own Health care website. Now we developed one SMART on Fhir application and integrating with our website. usually we test our SMART on Fhir app using some launchpad say for an example Open Epic, Cerner, Smart app launcher and so on. instead of launching SMART app from launch pad I want to launch it from our website.This is an EHR Launch not Standalone.

Comment: @Cooper So when I explore about EHR launch, we need to pass 2 parameters iss and launch. For "Smart App Launcher" launch token is generating using selected patient ans user. Now I want to know how about Cerner and  Open Epic? Am I Clear? or missed anything?

Comment: @kavithaK If you are acting as the SMART on FHIR auth server, and performing an EHR launch, then you are responsible for issuing your own launch token.  However if you are wanting to launch an app from your website, and have it be authorized for pulling FHIR data from an EHR, that is not EHR launch, that is Standalone launch.  When launching from your website, the end user will not be authenticated with the EHR, so they will need to authenticate (which the Standlone Launch flow supports).

Answer (score 1):

> A user selects an app from outside the EHR, for example by tapping an
>   app icon on a mobile phone home screen (or your website). This app will launch from its
>   registered URL without a launch id.

In your case this would be launching the app from your website and you can generate the launch parameter value. In this example xyz123

```
https://app/launch?iss=https%3A%2F%2Fehr%2Ffhir&launch=xyz123
```

> In order to obtain launch context and request authorization to access
>   FHIR resources, the app discovers the EHR authorization server’s OAuth
>   authorize and token endpoint URLs by querying their
>   .well-known/smart-configuration.json file.

At this point your app should capture the iss and launch URL parameters and would then fetch the FHIR server's conformance statement, usually /metadata at the end of the FHIR endpoint provided in the iss URL parameter.

```
https://ehr/fhir/metadata
```

> The app then can declare its launch context requirements by adding
>   specific scopes to the request it sends to the EHR’s authorization
>   server. The authorize endpoint will acquire the context the app needs
>   and make it available.

Here you would use the authorize endpoint provided in the /metadata conformance statement as well as the [required parameters](http://www.hl7.org/fhir/smart-app-launch/scopes-and-launch-context/index.html) to request a code.

> https://ehr/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=app-client-id&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapp%2Fafter-auth&launch=xyz123&scope=launch+patient%2FObservation.read+patient%2FPatient.read+openid+fhirUser&state=98wrghuwuogerg97&aud=https://ehr/fhir

When calling the authorize endpoint I have run into FHIR servers that provide a patient lookup screen to allow a user to select a patient if the scope is requesting patient access.

Now you will need to use the code returned to your redirect URI to send a request to the token endpoint provided in the /metadata conformance statement to retrieve an access token which would be used to authenticate any subsequent FHIR endpoint calls.

> https://ehr/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=123abc&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapp%2Fafter-auth

The response here will contain the access code

```js
{
  "access_token": "i8hweunweunweofiwweoijewiwe",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "scope": "patient/Observation.read patient/Patient.read",
  "intent": "client-ui-name",
  "patient":  "123",
  "encounter": "456"
}
```

Quotes and examples above are taken from [SMART App Launch Framework on HL7.org website](http://www.hl7.org/fhir/smart-app-launch/#standalone-launch-sequence)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is the standalone launch, but you are confusing it with EHR Launch.

You don't need to provide the `iss` and `launch` query params when launching your SMART app from your website.

> Apps using the **standalone launch** flow won’t have a launch id at this point. These apps can declare launch context requirements by adding specific scopes to the authorization request: for example, launch/patient to indicate that the app needs a patient ID, or launch/encounter to indicate it needs an encounter. The EHR’s “authorize” endpoint will take care of acquiring the context it needs (making it available to the app).
> For example, if your app needs patient context, the EHR may provide the end-user with a patient selection widget.

You may refer to the [Standalone Launch Sequence.](http://www.hl7.org/fhir/smart-app-launch/index.html#standalone-launch-sequence)